# Where to put the sizing css? In li, a, or img?

Tags: html, css, image

I am making an mobile web app, and I ran into this problem.

Currently my code is structured as follows:

```
    <ul class="app-lst">
        <li class="item-1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img1.jpg" alt="img">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-2">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img2.jpg" alt="img">
            </a>
        </li>
... etc.
    </ul>


CSS:
.item-1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
}

.app-lst li a {
    background-color: red;
}

.app-lst li a img {
}
```

Below image is the result I am trying to get. As you can see from the code above, Each boxes are `<li>`, and under it, there is `<a>` and under the link there is the content.

How would I go about with this for CSS?

-Should i adjust the box's size by putting width and height on `<li>` or `<a>`?

-Should i set the box's color by putting background-color on `<a>`?

-And finally, the image does not adjust to fit inside the parent `<a>`, so it extends the whole box if the image is larger. I tried putting "max-width: 100%" on the image, but no luck.

Also, since it is a mobile design I am controlling all the sizes with percentages. is this a good practice or should I do it with pixels?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

[image: Example]

Comment: For us to help, we'd really need to see the HTML that you would ideally like to render as that example image.  At the moment it's hard to tell from your image which tags are supposed to be rendered where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use your `<ul>` as a container that is set to 100% height/width, and then size your `<li>` elements based on that.  Then finally, make your `<img>` elements 100% height and width.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="app-lst">
    <li class="item-1">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-2">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-3">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-4">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-5">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="img"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.app-lst {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.app-lst li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.item-1, .item-2 {
    height: 75%;
}

.item-1 {
    width: 75%;
}

.item-2 {
    width: 25%;
}

.item-3, .item-4, .item-5 {
    height: 25%;
}

.item-3 {
    width: 10%;
}

.item-4 {
    width: 20%;
}

.item-5 {
    width: 70%;
}

.app-lst li img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6x1byfp/